# Sort an array with recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, recursion

To start off this is a homework assignment and I am just looking for some pointers on using recursion.

I have an array of psuedo random integers of size n. I need to sort the array from lowest highest. Below is the recursive sort function that I have created but I know that I am missing a piece but I am not sure what.

```
template <typename T>
void sort_array_recur(T* random_array,T n)
{
//stop case
    if(n = 1 )
    {
        if(random_array[n] < random_array[ n + 1 ])
        {
            T temp = random_array[n + 1];
            random_array[n] == random_array[n + 1];
            random_array[n + 1] == temp;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        sort_array_recur(random_array, (n - 1));

    }



}
```

I think what I am missing is some sort of insert function that also needs to be called recursively. I have also searched around and nothing seems particular to my situation (or at least I couldn't understand it as such). Thank you for your time in advance.

**EDIT:**

I guess I forgot to mention the spec says "sort the first n-1 elements of an n-element array. Then place the nth element in its proper position within the n-1 sorted elements". I guess I am not understanding how to sort the first the first n-1 elements of an array?

Comment: Try looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). That is an example of merge sort, one of the fastest (nlogn) algorithms.

Comment: Did you mean to use the assignment operator (=) and not the comparison operator(==) in several spots?

Comment: ah yes I did mean the assignment operator, thought I changed it through out.

Comment: Quicksort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is another classic algorithm used to teach recursive functions. It is also NlogN.

Comment: @EmileCormier Quick sort does look nice, however the spec says I have to "sort the first n-1 elements of an n-element array. Then place the nth element in its proper position within the n-1 sorted elements." I am still not able to wrap my brain around how to do this with recursion.

Comment: The spec sounds like a variant of insertion sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) that uses recursiveness. If you first take a look at the regular iterative insertion sort, then perhaps it might be easier for you to tackle your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to use recursion.  Your problem sorts a size n array.  The first step is sorting n-1 elements of that array.

Consider m = n-1.  Can you apply your problem to a size m array?  i.e. sort the first m-1 elements and then place the m'th element in its correct position?

Consider k = m-1.  Can you do the same with a size k array?

Do you see how you can use recursion with this problem?

Also consider how you will end the recursion; what will you do with a size 1 array?

Comment: I am pretty sure I understand what you are saying, you continually break the problem down until the stop case. But how do I know the element in `random_array[0]` is smaller than both `random_array[1]` and `random_array[2]`? That is where I seem to be hitting a road block when thinking recursively

Comment: @Nic: Imagine you have written your recursive sort function: `mySort(ary)`.  How would you use it to sort the n-element array?  Within that first task, how would you use it to sort the first (n-1) array elements?  Within that second task, how would you use it to sort the first (n-2) array elements?  Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @rossum if I used `mySort(ary)` for an n-element array I would have it find the lowest value and place that at `ary[0]` then search the array for the next lowest value and place it in `ary[1]`. so for a n-1 element array I would just do the same thing but after sorting I would place the n element in its proper spot? How do I know that the n element is truly in the right spot if I am taking it out of the sort function?

Comment: @Nic If you have mySort(ary) then you can use it to sort a sub-array of your original array.  Just set up the parameter correctly first.